# How to loop the following code?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I'm really new to java and I cannot find a way around this. I want to make a program that tells you that a number is either positive or negative, regardless if it is int or double. But after the program is executed, I want it to loop and ask again for input from the user, to execute the code again and again and again, as long as there is user input. Can I do that in java?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = "Input your number: ";
        System.out.println(userInput);

        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int z = in.nextInt();
            if (z > 0) {
                System.out.println(z + " is positive.");
            } else if (z < 0) {
                System.out.println(z + " is negative.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(z + " is equal to 0.");
            }
        } else if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            double x = in.nextDouble();
            if (x > 0) {
                System.out.println(x + " is positive.");
            } else if (x < 0) {
                System.out.println(x + " is negative.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(x + " is equal to 0.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hey! Only numbers!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: with a [while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) most likely

Comment: What do you mean "as long as there is user input"?  How should the program know when to stop?

Comment: try doing something like this: `while (i = System.in.read() != "")`

Comment: with a while loop and ask whether the user wants to input a number or not.

Comment: He seems very new in java and programming language. @RC.

Comment: Yup, I am really new. Learning java for almost two weeks.

Comment: @DeepakOjha that's why I linked to a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one of the approach which is good start for you to understand what wonders pattern matching can do in Java and it can be improved by testing it against exhaustive data points.

This also shows how to use while-loop, overloading methods and ternary operator instead of nested if-then-else.

As you are learning, you should also use debugging feature of editors and also use `system.out.println` to understand what code is doing.

I am ending the program when user presses just enter (empty string).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String userInput = "Input your number: ";
            System.out.print(userInput);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            // look for integer (+ve, -ve or 0)
            if (input.matches("^-?[0-9]+$")) {
                int z = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println(display(z));
            // look for double (+ve, -ve or 0)
            } else if (input.matches("^-?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$")) {
                double z = Double.parseDouble(input);
                System.out.println(display(z));
            // look for end of program by user
            } else if (input.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("Good Bye!!");
                break;
            // look for bad input
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hey! Only numbers!");
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    // handle integer and display message appropriately
    private static String display(int d) {
        return (d>0) ? (d + " is positive") : (d<0) ? (d + " is negative") : (d + " is equal to 0");
    }

    // handle double and display message appropriately    
    private static String display(double d) {
        return (d>0) ? (d + " is positive") : (d<0) ? (d + " is negative") : (d + " is equal to 0");
    }
}
```

Sample Run:

```
Input your number: 0
0 is equal to 0
Input your number: 0.0
0.0 is equal to 0
Input your number: -0
0 is equal to 0
Input your number: -0.0
-0.0 is equal to 0
Input your number: 12
12 is positive
Input your number: -12
-12 is negative
Input your number: 12.0
12.0 is positive
Input your number: -12.0
-12.0 is negative
Input your number: 12-12
Hey! Only numbers!
Input your number: ---12
Hey! Only numbers!
Input your number:
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Even if the code is too complicated for me at this point, I will take it step by step to see why it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = new Console();
        while(true) {
            // Take your input
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userInput = "Input your number: ";
            System.out.println(userInput);

            if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                int z = in.nextInt();
                if (z > 0) {
                    System.out.println(z + " is positive.");
                } else if (z < 0) {
                    System.out.println(z + " is negative.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(z + " is equal to 0.");
                }
            } else if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
                double x = in.nextDouble();
                if (x > 0) {
                    System.out.println(x + " is positive.");
                } else if (x < 0) {
                    System.out.println(x + " is negative.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(x + " is equal to 0.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hey! Only numbers!");
            }
            // Ask for exit
            System.out.print("Want to quit? Y/N")
            String input = console.readLine();
            if("Y".equals(input))
            {
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers without any explanation are generally not considered acceptable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. :)
But possibly he will understand this code. I can write it much better than this. But he is also learning cannot go higher at one instance.

Comment: I would still have downvoted it even if the code were much better.  There needs to be some kind of explanation in any Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: I have made two comments in code. If code works he might work and pay attention on few new stuff. Anyways I just wanted to help.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Console cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - Console cannot be resolved

I get this error on line 5.